# Como copiar informações de uma coluna no googlePlanilhas sem repetir dados, caso tenham dados repetidos?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-sheets, planilha

eu tenho uma planilha em que uma coluna consta nomes, eu preciso copiar esses dados para uma outra coluna, porém sem copiar as repetições dos nomes, exemplo:

```
Coluna A       Coluna C
Américo        Américo
Mauricio       Mauricio
Bruno          Bruno
José           José
Mauricio       Marta
Marta
Bruno
```

Eu achei uma formula na internet, mas ela não funciona, segue a formula
=INDEX ($A$2: $A$10, MATCH(0, COUNTIF ($C$1: C1, $A$2: $A$10), 0))

Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função:

`UNIQUE`

No seu caso o uso ficaria da seguinte forma:

`=UNIQUE(A2:A)`